# Return a 2D array from the parameters of a JavaScript function where a semi-colon means a new row

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this simple JavaScript functions that works very well that returns an array that contains the parameters (arguments) for example 1,2,3 for that function:

```
function array() {
var a = Array.from(arguments);
return a; 
}
```

I now want to apply the same logic (pass a functions parameters to an array) to a JavaScript function called matrix. Something like this:

```
matrix(1,2,3;4,5,6) where a semi-colon (;) indicates a new row in the 2D array.
```

The function take the parameters (or arguments) and returns a 2D JavaScript array like this:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

What JavaScript code can do this in the most efficient and simplest way?

I have tried to convert the array to a string and then apply split and back to array but I have not managed to get it to work.

The reason why I want to do this is because on my onscreen keyboard on my Microsoft surface tablet it is much easier and much faster to type in a semi-colon than it is to switch keyboard and type in 4 square brackets! Typing in 4 square brackets fast is also often very error-prone. I usually end up with 2-3 brackets when I type fast and then I always have to go back and double check if all 4 brackets were entered correctly and at the right place. A big time killer for me when I type in a lot of JavaScript arrays.

Comment: Have `"1,2,3;4,5,6"` as a string, simply split by `;`, then map and split by `,` : `"1,2,3;4,5,6".split(";").map(subArr => subArr.split(","))` (**Edit : wrote an answer for better readability**)

Comment: thx. I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried to convert the array to a string and then apply split and back to array but I have not managed to get it to work.

Well if having a string as input works for you, you can simply do it by splitting by `;`, then map and split again each sub-array by `,`, like this :

```js
const yourString = "1,2,3;4,5,6"

const your2DArray = yourString.split(";").map(subArr => subArr.split(","))

console.log(your2DArray)
```

---

Edit :
As sairfan noticed, the code snippet above will not work on IE since it does not support arrow functions. To fix this, you can simply use a plain function :

```js
const yourString = "1,2,3;4,5,6"

const your2DArray = yourString.split(";").map(function (subArr) {
  return subArr.split(",")
})

console.log(your2DArray)
```

Comment: @sairfan Why should it have to?

Comment: @sairfan to make it work with IE, you can replace the arrow function by a plain function with the `function` keyword. I edited my answer.

Comment: @TylerRoper it is supported. IE partially supports `const` : https://caniuse.com/#search=const But it really is time to ditch that browser.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with what you're suggesting is that it isn't valid to have a semi-colon within the arguments of a function. This means you'd have to perform the workaround of passing a *string* instead, which restricts your `matrix` method to only creating string arrays.

As an alternative, I'd suggest passing an additional argument that you can use to distinguish a break. In the example below, I've used `_`. This allows you to pass arguments as other types.

```js
const _ = {}; //represents a break

function matrix() {
  let args = Array.from(arguments);
  return args.reduce((out, arg) => {
    let last = out.pop();
    return arg === _ 
      ? [...out, last, []]
      : [...out, [...last, arg]]
  }, [[]]);
}

let result = matrix(1,2,3,_,4,5,6);
console.log(result);

//Pass any type
let variable = true;
let result2 = matrix({},"Hello",_,variable,(5+5));
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: thank you for your provide solution. I will run and compare both solutions to find the best one and you are right that the other answer returns an array with strings. I need more time to run both provided solutions and compare.